# Basic Standalone JPA example with Postgres using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jpa

I have been trying to get a very basic standalone JPA example to work with Postgres using the Eclipse IDE.

I have a persistance.xml defined which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>package.class</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="scott" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="tiger" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This file lives in the src/main/resources/META-INF folder. I have included the src/main/resources folder to my source directory in eclipse. I have one simple Entity defined named User. When  I try and create that entity

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory 
         = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");
     EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
     EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
     try {
         User user = new User();
         user.setEnabled(false);
         user.setEmailId("test@test.com");
         tx.begin();
          em.persist(user);
         tx.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         em.getTransaction().rollback();
     } finally {
         em.close();
     }
```

I get the following exception - `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named sample`

It seems like my persistance.xml file is not being picked up. Where does the JPA framework look to load the persistance.xml file?

Comment: This was a dumb mistake. The file needs to called persistence.xml and not persistance.xml.

Comment: I suggest you post this as a answer to you own question. Easier to see the solution

Answer (score 6):

This was a dumb mistake. The file needs to called persistence.xml and not persistance.xml.